Нет звука в майнкрафт при окрытии лаунчера через exe
При открытии моего лаунчера через .py звук в майнкрафте есть , но как только я компилирую его в exe звука в майнкрафте нет.Проблемм с файлами и командой запуска нет.
Вот фрагмент для запуска майнкрафта:
# Путь к javaw.exe
java_path = r'runtime\jre-legacy\windows\jre-legacy\bin\javaw.exe'

# Команда и аргументы
command = [
    java_path,
    "-Dos.name=Windows 10",
    "-Dos.version=10.0",
    "-Djava.library.path=versions\\Forge_1.12.2\\natives",
    "-cp",
    "libraries\\net\\minecraftforge\\forge\\1.12.2-14.23.5.2860\\forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\ow2\\asm\\asm-debug-all\\5.2\\asm-debug-all-5.2.jar;"
    "libraries\\net\\minecraft\\launchwrapper\\1.12\\launchwrapper-1.12.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\jline\\jline\\3.5.1\\jline-3.5.1.jar;"
    "libraries\\com\\typesafe\\akka\\akka-actor_2.11\\2.3.3\\akka-actor_2.11-2.3.3.jar;"
    "libraries\\com\\typesafe\\config\\1.2.1\\config-1.2.1.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\scala-lang\\scala-actors-migration_2.11\\1.1.0\\scala-actors-migration_2.11-1.1.0.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\scala-lang\\scala-compiler\\2.11.1\\scala-compiler-2.11.1.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\scala-lang\\plugins\\scala-continuations-library_2.11\\1.0.2_mc\\scala-continuations-library_2.11-1.0.2_mc.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\scala-lang\\plugins\\scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1\\1.0.2_mc\\scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1-1.0.2_mc.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\scala-lang\\scala-library\\2.11.1\\scala-library-2.11.1.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\scala-lang\\scala-parser-combinators_2.11\\1.0.1\\scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.1.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\scala-lang\\scala-reflect\\2.11.1\\scala-reflect-2.11.1.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\scala-lang\\scala-swing_2.11\\1.0.1\\scala-swing_2.11-1.0.1.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\scala-lang\\scala-xml_2.11\\1.0.2\\scala-xml_2.11-1.0.2.jar;"
    "libraries\\lzma\\lzma\\0.0.1\\lzma-0.0.1.jar;"
    "libraries\\java3d\\vecmath\\1.5.2\\vecmath-1.5.2.jar;"
    "libraries\\net\\sf\\trove4j\\trove4j\\3.0.3\\trove4j-3.0.3.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\apache\\maven\\maven-artifact\\3.5.3\\maven-artifact-3.5.3.jar;"
    "libraries\\net\\sf\\jopt-simple\\jopt-simple\\5.0.3\\jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\apache\\logging\\log4j\\log4j-api\\2.15.0\\log4j-api-2.15.0.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\apache\\logging\\log4j\\log4j-core\\2.15.0\\log4j-core-2.15.0.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\tlauncher\\patchy\\1.3.9\\patchy-1.3.9.jar;"
    "libraries\\oshi-project\\oshi-core\\1.1\\oshi-core-1.1.jar;"
    "libraries\\net\\java\\dev\\jna\\jna\\4.4.0\\jna-4.4.0.jar;"
    "libraries\\net\\java\\dev\\jna\\platform\\3.4.0\\platform-3.4.0.jar;"
    "libraries\\com\\ibm\\icu\\icu4j-core-mojang\\51.2\\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;"
    "libraries\\com\\paulscode\\codecjorbis\\20101023\\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;"
    "libraries\\com\\paulscode\\codecwav\\20101023\\codecwav-20101023.jar;"
    "libraries\\com\\paulscode\\libraryjavasound\\20101123\\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;"
    "libraries\\com\\paulscode\\librarylwjglopenal\\20100824\\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;"
    "libraries\\com\\paulscode\\soundsystem\\20120107\\soundsystem-20120107.jar;"
    "libraries\\io\\netty\\netty-all\\4.1.9.Final\\netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar;"
    "libraries\\com\\google\\guava\\guava\\21.0\\guava-21.0.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\apache\\commons\\commons-lang3\\3.5\\commons-lang3-3.5.jar;"
    "libraries\\commons-io\\commons-io\\2.5\\commons-io-2.5.jar;"
    "libraries\\commons-codec\\commons-codec\\1.10\\commons-codec-1.10.jar;"
    "libraries\\net\\java\\jinput\\jinput\\2.0.5\\jinput-2.0.5.jar;"
    "libraries\\net\\java\\jutils\\jutils\\1.0.0\\jutils-1.0.0.jar;"
    "libraries\\com\\google\\code\\gson\\gson\\2.8.0\\gson-2.8.0.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\tlauncher\\authlib\\1.6.251\\authlib-1.6.251.jar;"
    "libraries\\com\\mojang\\realms\\1.10.22\\realms-1.10.22.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\apache\\commons\\commons-compress\\1.8.1\\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\apache\\httpcomponents\\httpclient\\4.3.3\\httpclient-4.3.3.jar;"
    "libraries\\commons-logging\\commons-logging\\1.1.3\\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\apache\\httpcomponents\\httpcore\\4.3.2\\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;"
    "libraries\\it\\unimi\\dsi\\fastutil\\7.1.0\\fastutil-7.1.0.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\apache\\logging\\log4j\\log4j-api\\2.8.1\\log4j-api-2.8.1.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\apache\\logging\\log4j\\log4j-core\\2.8.1\\log4j-core-2.8.1.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\lwjgl\\lwjgl\\lwjgl\\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;"
    "libraries\\org\\lwjgl\\lwjgl\\lwjgl_util\\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\\lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;"
    "libraries\\com\\mojang\\text2speech\\1.10.3\\text2speech-1.10.3.jar;"
    "versions\\Forge_1.12.2\\Forge_1.12.2.jar",
    f"-Xmx{memory_value}M",  # Устанавливаем значение памяти
    "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions",
    "-XX:+UseG1GC",
    "-XX:G1NewSizePercent=20",
    "-XX:G1ReservePercent=20",
    "-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50",
    "-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M",
    "-Dfml.ignoreInvalidMinecraftCertificates=true",
    "-Dfml.ignorePatchDiscrepancies=true",
    "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true",
    "-Dminecraft.applet.TargetDirectory=resources",
    "-DlibraryDirectory=libraries",
    "-Dlog4j.configurationFile=assets\\log_configs\\client-1.12.xml",
    "net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch",
    "--username", player_name,  # Устанавливаем имя пользователя
    "--version", "Forge_1.12.2",
    "--gameDir", "resources",
    "--assetsDir", "assets",
    "--assetIndex", "1.12",
    "--uuid", "0b7ecd22096a455eabac100d8fa7e5e5",
    "--accessToken", "null",
    "--userType", "mojang",
    "--tweakClass", "net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker",
    "--versionType", "Forge",
    "--width", "925",
    "--height", "530"
]

Запуск процесса
try:
    subprocess.Popen(command)  # Запускаем Minecraft в новом процессе
     # Блокируем кнопку "Играть" после запуска Minecraft
    play_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

    # Разблокируем кнопку "Играть" через 30 секунд
    play_button.after(30000, lambda: play_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL))

except Exception as e:
    with open("error_log.txt", "w") as log:
        log.write(f"Error: {e}")

